# better tool than netstat

Tags: windows, networking, port

OS: Windows server/ Windows XP

Is there any port scan tool that can do what netstat does and also has a filter feature, so that unnecessary connections can be hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative is [CurrPorts : Monitoring TCP/IP network connections on Windows](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html)

Comment: Very nice! And better than the one of sysinternal

Answer (score 7):

You could also just pipe the output of netstat into find e.g.

```
netstat -n | find "10.0."
netstat | find /I "pcname"
netstat | find "ESTABLSIHED"
```

Comment: I do this a lot, people always turn their head sideways when I do it but once they see the result their good!

Comment: I normally go one step further and install a grep for windows but find works well enough for this.

Comment: Yep, +1. Piping into find and not having to install 3rd party tools works just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sysinternal's [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) may do what you are looking for, if a GUI tool is fine for what you are trying to do.

Comment: How do you filter out connections in TCPView?

Comment: I've just fired up my old copy and it seems that you can't. I must be thinking of some other tool - I'll try remember what that is...