# Telnet remote port on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking

On WinXP/Win2k3, we can use telnet   to if tell remote port is open. Since there's no telnet on Win 7, is there any other lite utility can do this?

Comment: See this thread...http://superuser.com/questions/143508/better-tool-than-netstat

Comment: You can enable Telnet in Windows 7, go to Programs and features, then Turn Windows Features on or Off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) is a telnet/ssh client that most people recommend. Many putty forks might work. Alternately you can copy hyperterminal off an older windows install i think - by copying the hypertrm.dll and hypertrm.exe files.

If you merely want to check for open ports, how about [nmap](http://nmap.org/)? Amongst other things, it does port scanning.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear. I am looking for a port testing tool (check if port is open or not).

Comment: nmap perhaps? it does a whole lot more, but yes, it scans ports. Your question seemed to be specifically asking for telnet to me tho